# Is there any way by which I can get all the quarterly result data for each of the stocks (200+) and store it in excel using python?

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

Link of the website: http://opstra.definedge.com/historical-results-timings . So, there is quarterly result dates for each corresponding stocks and I want to store each dates for the corresponding stock in excel. I am new to python hence don't know how to web scrape it. I tried but not working. Below is the code:

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Python_module\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://opstra.definedge.com/historical-results-timings")

driver.maximize_window()

#obj=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("searchLanguage"))
#obj.select_by_index(0)

obj=Select(driver.find_element_by_class("v-input_slot"))
obj.select_by_index(10)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Documents\\Python_module\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://opstra.definedge.com/historical-results-timings")

driver.maximize_window()

#obj=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("searchLanguage"))
#obj.select_by_index(0)

obj=Select(driver.find_element_by_class("v-input_slot"))
obj.select_by_index(10)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: Yes it is possible.

The long answer:
Python provides many libraries to scrape data from the web like [BeatifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and to write Excel like [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/).

However, I guess you could also find an API to collect the data without the scraping technique.

Comment: hi, i tried using selenium but it is not working somehow it is not working. this is the code: from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Documents\\Python_module\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://opstra.definedge.com/historical-results-timings")

driver.maximize_window()

#obj=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("searchLanguage"))
#obj.select_by_index(0)

obj=Select(driver.find_element_by_class("v-input_slot"))
obj.select_by_index(10)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need selenium. You can grab the stock list by using the same source js file as the page uses to update the stocks as you scroll. You can grab this with requests and then iterate over the stock list issuing xhr requests to get the json data which feeds the page. I concatenate the separate stock dataframes together and use ast to convert the string `stocks` to a list `stocks`.

I re-use the connection via `Session`.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import ast

with requests.Session() as s:
    listings = s.get('http://opstra.definedge.com/js/view-HistoricalResultsTimings-vue.f75d8b5c.js')
    stocks = listings.text.split('stocks:')[1].split(',columns')[0]
    stocks = ast.literal_eval(stocks)
    headers = ['Date', 'Quarter', 'Symbol', 'Time', 'Year']
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = headers)
    for item in stocks:
        data = requests.get(baseURL + item).json()
        dfCurrent = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df = pd.concat([df, dfCurrent])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.csv", encoding='utf-8')
```